# Thymeleaf Checkbox Binding - sending boolean instead of value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a checkbox binding but when I try to pass the value ( ${phone.number} ) inside the checkbox to request it at the backend, the value is always a boolean. I added a photo to show the browser inspect.
I tried everything but I don`t have idea what is missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html lang="fr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<th:block th:insert="commons/head" />

<script th:src="@{/js/index.js}"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <th:block th:insert="commons/top-menu" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="clearfix mt-2">
      <h3 class="float-left" th:text="#{topmenu.title}" />
    </div>

    <form id="other" th:action="@{/phone}" th:field="${phones}" method="get">
      
      <div class="form-inline mt-2" style="margin-bottom:50px">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm mr-3 w-75" id="search-value" name="search" type="text" th:value="${search}" th:placeholder="#{index.search}" aria-label="Search">
        
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="select" style="display:inline-block; border:none;background: transparent;">
                 <img th:src="@{/img/commons/search.png}" style="float:left;margin-right:0.5em" height="25" width="25">
              </button>           
              
              <button type="submit" name="action" value="include" style="display:inline-block; border:none;background: transparent;">
           Add
        </button>
        
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="remove" style="display:inline-block; border:none;background: transparent;">
           Remove
        </button>        
      </div>

     
  </form>
        
        <form class="form-horizontal"
          th:action="@{/phone/save}"
          th:object="${resourceDto}"
          method="post">
        <fieldset>
        
          <span class="pull-right">
                <input type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-success" th:value="Save">
          </span>
          
              <table id="activitiesTable" class="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr class="d-flex">
                    <th scope="col" class="col-1"></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col-2"><p th:text="#{number}" /></th>          
                    <th scope="col" class="col-2"><p th:text="#{statusSolicitation}" /></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col-2"><p th:text="#{externalList}" /></th>                  
                    <th scope="col" class="col-2"><p th:text="#{internalList}" /></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col-2"><p th:text="#{withdrawalDate}" /></th>          
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr class="activitycode d-flex" th:each="phone : ${selectedPhones}" >
                    <td class="col-1 font-weight-bold">
                      <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{phones}" th:value="${phone.number}">
                      </div>            
                    </td>          
                    <td th:text="${phone.number}" th:style="${phone.phonable? 'color:black':'color:red'}" class="col-2 font-weight-bold"/>          
                    <td th:text="${phone.phonable}? #{statusOk}: #{statusRemoved}" th:style="${phone.phonable? 'color:black':'color:red'}" class="col-2 font-weight-bold"/>
                    <td th:text="${phone.externalList}? #{yes}: #{no}" class="col-2 font-weight-bold"/>
                    <td th:text="${phone.internalList}? #{yes}: #{no}" class="col-2 font-weight-bold"/>
                    <td th:text="${phone.withdrawalDate}" class="col-2 font-weight-bold"/>          
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
    
        </fieldset>
      </form>    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
import java.util.List;
    
public class ResourceDto {

  private List<String> phones;

  /**
   * @return the phones
   */
  public List<String> getPhones() {
    return phones;
  }

  /**
   * @param phones the phones to set
   */
  public void setPhones(List<String> phones) {
    this.phones = phones;
  }
}
```

---

```
  @PostMapping(value="/phone/save")
  public String includePhones(@ModelAttribute("resourceDto") ResourceDto phones) {

     System.out.println(phones.getPhones());

    return "index";
  }
```

[Brownser Inspection - showing value = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzgI1.png)